# Prove if $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small then $f(\underline{p}+\epsilon\underline{n}\left(\underline{p}\right))>0$

Tags: real-analysis, vector-analysis

A region in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for which $\exists$ a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\ \rightarrow\ \mathbb{R}$ with following properties:

(i) all partial derivatives of f are continuous,

(ii) $\Omega = \left \{\underline{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \ f\left(\underline{x}\right)<0 \right \}$ and

(iii)$\nabla f\left(\underline{x}\right) \neq 0\, \forall \underline{x} \in  \partial{\Omega}$ where $\partial{\Omega} := \left \{\underline{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \ f\left(\underline{x}\right)=0 \right \}$ is the boundary of $\Omega$

$f$ is called a defining function of the set $\Omega$.

Condition (iii) in the definition of a region allows us to define the
outward unit normal $\underline{n}$ to $\Omega$ by $\underline{n}\left(\underline{p}\right) := \frac{\nabla f\left(\underline{p}\right)}{ \left\|{\nabla f\left(\underline{p}\right)}\right\|} \forall \underline{p} \in \partial{\Omega}$

> Observe that, if $\epsilon>0$ is sufficiently small then $f(\underline{p}+\epsilon\underline{n}\left(\underline{p}\right))>0$. (How do I prove this?) and therefore $\underline{p}+\epsilon\underline{n}\left(\underline{p}\right) \notin \Omega$ (this makes sense)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{f(p+\epsilon n(p))-f(p)}{\epsilon}=\langle \nabla f(p),n(p)\rangle =\frac{\langle \nabla f(p),\nabla f(p) \rangle}{\|\nabla f(p) \|} = \|\nabla f(p) \| > 0.
$$
So for $\epsilon$ small, you have $$
f(p+\epsilon(p))>f(p)=0.
$$

Comment: How did you get the last equality (before >0)?

Comment: Also how did you get that limit?

Comment: @George 1. I just edited the answer to explain the equality 2. the limit is the definition of directional derivative.